# Uploadify get file dialog to show last folder in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I am using uploadify.  In Chrome, once I have uploaded one file, the next time I click the button I am pointed to the folder that I uploaded the previous file from.  That is what I want to happen.  In IE8 and IE9 this does not happen, I am taken back to the desktop.

Is there a way to specify this behaviour?  On some other sites, such as here http://www.yourdesign.co.uk/personalised-mugs/standard-mug, I am taken to the most recent folder even in IE.

Thanks for reading